# Unable to Save my Gallery bitmap into gallery

Tags: java, android

My project is about to censor the picture. It works like this: user choose a photo from gallery and  when select an area of photo , this area change to the other color. 
It works fine and my problem is that I couldn't save it my gallery.Saving picture to gallery is easy and I do it many time without error. But now I got no error and may method doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
    public boolean save() {
    if (mTouchRects.isEmpty() || bmMosaicLayer == null) {
        return false;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmBaseLayer, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmMosaicLayer, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.save();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to write image content");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in my activity :

```
else if (view.equals(btSave)) {
            boolean succced = mvImage.save();
            String text = "save image "
                    + (succced ? " succeed" : " failed");
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
```

here is my full code:

```
 public class MosaicView extends ViewGroup {
  public static final String TAG = "MosaicView";

public static enum Effect {
    GRID, COLOR, BLUR,
};

public static enum Mode {
    GRID, PATH,
}

// default image inner padding, in dip pixels
private static final int INNER_PADDING = 6;

// default grid width, in dip pixels
private static final int GRID_WIDTH = 5;

// default grid width, in dip pixels
private static final int PATH_WIDTH = 20;

// default stroke rectangle color
private static final int STROKE_COLOR = 0xff2a5caa;

// default stroke width, in pixels
private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 6;

private int mImageWidth;
private int mImageHeight;

private Bitmap bmBaseLayer;
private Bitmap bmCoverLayer;
private Bitmap bmMosaicLayer;

private Point startPoint;

private int mGridWidth;
private int mPathWidth;

private int mStrokeWidth;

private int mStrokeColor;

private String inPath;
private String outPath;

private Effect mEffect;
private Mode mMode;

private Rect mImageRect;

private Paint mPaint;

private Rect mTouchRect;
private List<Rect> mTouchRects;

private Path mTouchPath;
private List<Rect> mEraseRects;

private int mMosaicColor;
private int mPadding;

private List<Path> mTouchPaths;
private List<Path> mErasePaths;

private boolean mMosaic;

public MosaicView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initImage();
}

public MosaicView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initImage();
}

private void initImage() {
    mMosaic = true;

    mTouchRects = new ArrayList<Rect>();
    mEraseRects = new ArrayList<Rect>();

    mTouchPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    mErasePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    mStrokeWidth = STROKE_WIDTH;
    mStrokeColor = STROKE_COLOR;

    mPadding = dp2px(INNER_PADDING);

    mPathWidth = dp2px(PATH_WIDTH);
    mGridWidth = dp2px(GRID_WIDTH);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
    mPaint.setColor(mStrokeColor);

    mImageRect = new Rect();

    setWillNotDraw(false);

    mMode = Mode.PATH;
    mEffect = Effect.GRID;
}

public void setSrcPath(String absPath) {
    File file = new File(absPath);
    if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "invalid file path " + absPath);
        return;
    }

    reset();

    inPath = absPath;
    String fileName = file.getName();
    String parent = file.getParent();
    int index = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    String stem = fileName.substring(0, index);
    String newStem = stem + "_mosaic";
    fileName = fileName.replace(stem, newStem);
    outPath = parent + "/" + fileName;

    Size size = BitmapUtil.getImageSize(inPath);
    mImageWidth = size.width;
    mImageHeight = size.height;

    bmBaseLayer = BitmapUtil.getImage(absPath);

    bmCoverLayer = getCoverLayer();
    bmMosaicLayer = null;

    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

public void setEffect(Effect effect) {
    if (mEffect == effect) {
        Log.d(TAG, "duplicated effect " + effect);
        return;
    }

    this.mEffect = effect;
    if (bmCoverLayer != null) {
        bmCoverLayer.recycle();
    }

    bmCoverLayer = getCoverLayer();
    if (mMode == Mode.GRID) {
        updateGridMosaic();
    } else if (mMode == Mode.PATH) {
        updatePathMosaic();
    }

    invalidate();
}

public void setMode(Mode mode) {
    if (mMode == mode) {
        Log.d(TAG, "duplicated mode " + mode);
        return;
    }

    if (bmMosaicLayer != null) {
        bmMosaicLayer.recycle();
        bmMosaicLayer = null;
    }

    this.mMode = mode;

    invalidate();
}

private Bitmap getCoverLayer() {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (mEffect == Effect.GRID) {
        bitmap = getGridMosaic();
    } else if (mEffect == Effect.COLOR) {
        bitmap = getColorMosaic();
    } else if (mEffect == Effect.BLUR) {
        bitmap = getBlurMosaic();
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private Bitmap getColorMosaic() {
    if (mImageWidth <= 0 || mImageHeight <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(mMosaicColor);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    canvas.save();
    return bitmap;
}

private Bitmap getBlurMosaic() {
    if (mImageWidth <= 0 || mImageHeight <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    if (bmBaseLayer == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtil.blur(bmBaseLayer);
    return bitmap;
}

private Bitmap getGridMosaic() {
    if (mImageWidth <= 0 || mImageHeight <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    int horCount = (int) Math.ceil(mImageWidth / (float) mGridWidth);
    int verCount = (int) Math.ceil(mImageHeight / (float) mGridWidth);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    for (int horIndex = 0; horIndex < horCount; ++horIndex) {
        for (int verIndex = 0; verIndex < verCount; ++verIndex) {
            int l = mGridWidth * horIndex;
            int t = mGridWidth * verIndex;
            int r = l + mGridWidth;
            if (r > mImageWidth) {
                r = mImageWidth;
            }
            int b = t + mGridWidth;
            if (b > mImageHeight) {
                b = mImageHeight;
            }
            int color = bmBaseLayer.getPixel(l, t);
            Rect rect = new Rect(l, t, r, b);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
        }
    }
    canvas.save();
    return bitmap;
}

public boolean isSaved() {
    return (bmCoverLayer == null);
}

public void setOutPath(String absPath) {
    this.outPath = absPath;
}

public void setGridWidth(int width) {
    this.mGridWidth = dp2px(width);
}

public void setPathWidth(int width) {
    this.mPathWidth = dp2px(width);
}

public int getGridWidth() {
    return this.mGridWidth;
}

public void setStrokeColor(int color) {
    this.mStrokeColor = color;
    mPaint.setColor(mStrokeColor);
}

public void setMosaicColor(int color) {
    this.mMosaicColor = color;
}

public int getStrokeColor() {
    return this.mStrokeColor;
}

public void setStrokeWidth(int width) {
    this.mStrokeWidth = width;
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
}

public int getStrokeWidth() {
    return this.mStrokeWidth;
}

public void setErase(boolean erase) {
    this.mMosaic = !erase;
}

public void clear() {
    mTouchRects.clear();
    mEraseRects.clear();

    mTouchPaths.clear();
    mErasePaths.clear();

    if (bmMosaicLayer != null) {
        bmMosaicLayer.recycle();
        bmMosaicLayer = null;
    }

    invalidate();
}

public boolean reset() {
    if (bmCoverLayer != null) {
        bmCoverLayer.recycle();
        bmCoverLayer = null;
    }
    if (bmBaseLayer != null) {
        bmBaseLayer.recycle();
        bmBaseLayer = null;
    }
    if (bmMosaicLayer != null) {
        bmMosaicLayer.recycle();
        bmMosaicLayer = null;
    }
    mTouchRects.clear();
    mEraseRects.clear();

    mTouchPaths.clear();
    mErasePaths.clear();
    return true;
}

public boolean save() {
    if (mTouchRects.isEmpty() || bmMosaicLayer == null) {
        return false;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmBaseLayer, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmMosaicLayer, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.save();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to write image content");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    int action = event.getAction();
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    Log.d(TAG, "action " + action + " x " + x + " y " + y);
    if (mMode == Mode.GRID) {
        onGridEvent(action, x, y);
    } else if (mMode == Mode.PATH) {
        onPathEvent(action, x, y);
    }
    return true;
}

private void onGridEvent(int action, int x, int y) {
    if (x >= mImageRect.left && x <= mImageRect.right
            && y >= mImageRect.top && y <= mImageRect.bottom) {
        int left = x;
        int right = x;
        int top = y;
        int bottom = y;
        if (startPoint == null) {
            startPoint = new Point();
            startPoint.set(x, y);
            mTouchRect = new Rect();
        } else {
            left = startPoint.x < x ? startPoint.x : x;
            top = startPoint.y < y ? startPoint.y : y;
            right = x > startPoint.x ? x : startPoint.x;
            bottom = y > startPoint.y ? y : startPoint.y;
        }
        mTouchRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (mMosaic) {
            mTouchRects.add(mTouchRect);
        } else {
            mEraseRects.add(mTouchRect);
        }
        mTouchRect = null;
        startPoint = null;
        updateGridMosaic();
    }

    invalidate();
}

private void onPathEvent(int action, int x, int y) {
    if (mImageWidth <= 0 || mImageHeight <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (x < mImageRect.left || x > mImageRect.right || y < mImageRect.top
            || y > mImageRect.bottom) {
        return;
    }

    float ratio = (mImageRect.right - mImageRect.left)
            / (float) mImageWidth;
    x = (int) ((x - mImageRect.left) / ratio);
    y = (int) ((y - mImageRect.top) / ratio);

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mTouchPath = new Path();
        mTouchPath.moveTo(x, y);
        if (mMosaic) {
            mTouchPaths.add(mTouchPath);
        } else {
            mErasePaths.add(mTouchPath);
        }
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        mTouchPath.lineTo(x, y);
        updatePathMosaic();
        invalidate();
    }
}

private void updatePathMosaic() {
    if (mImageWidth <= 0 || mImageHeight <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (bmMosaicLayer != null) {
        bmMosaicLayer.recycle();
    }
    bmMosaicLayer = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);

    Bitmap bmTouchLayer = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(mPathWidth);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmTouchLayer);

    for (Path path : mTouchPaths) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    for (Path path : mErasePaths) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    canvas.setBitmap(bmMosaicLayer);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmCoverLayer, 0, 0, null);

    paint.reset();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmTouchLayer, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    canvas.save();

    bmTouchLayer.recycle();
    Log.d(TAG, "updatePathMosaic " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
}

private void updateGridMosaic() {
    if (mImageWidth <= 0 || mImageHeight <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (bmMosaicLayer != null) {
        bmMosaicLayer.recycle();
    }
    bmMosaicLayer = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);

    float ratio = (mImageRect.right - mImageRect.left)
            / (float) mImageWidth;
    Bitmap bmTouchLayer = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = null;
    canvas = new Canvas(bmTouchLayer);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(mStrokeColor);

    for (Rect rect : mTouchRects) {
        int left = (int) ((rect.left - mImageRect.left) / ratio);
        int right = (int) ((rect.right - mImageRect.left) / ratio);
        int top = (int) ((rect.top - mImageRect.top) / ratio);
        int bottom = (int) ((rect.bottom - mImageRect.top) / ratio);
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
    }

    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    for (Rect rect : mEraseRects) {
        int left = (int) ((rect.left - mImageRect.left) / ratio);
        int right = (int) ((rect.right - mImageRect.left) / ratio);
        int top = (int) ((rect.top - mImageRect.top) / ratio);
        int bottom = (int) ((rect.bottom - mImageRect.top) / ratio);
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
    }

    canvas.setBitmap(bmMosaicLayer);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmCoverLayer, 0, 0, null);

    paint.reset();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmTouchLayer, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    canvas.save();

    bmTouchLayer.recycle();
    Log.d(TAG, "updateGridMosaic " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.d(TAG, "onDraw canvas " + canvas + " mTouchRect " + mTouchRect);

    if (bmBaseLayer != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmBaseLayer, null, mImageRect, null);
    }

    if (bmMosaicLayer != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmMosaicLayer, null, mImageRect, null);
    }

    if (mTouchRect != null) {
        canvas.drawRect(mTouchRect, mPaint);
    }
}

protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom) {
    if (mImageWidth <= 0 || mImageHeight <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    int contentWidth = right - left;
    int contentHeight = bottom - top;
    int viewWidth = contentWidth - mPadding * 2;
    int viewHeight = contentHeight - mPadding * 2;
    float widthRatio = viewWidth / ((float) mImageWidth);
    float heightRatio = viewHeight / ((float) mImageHeight);
    float ratio = widthRatio < heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;
    int realWidth = (int) (mImageWidth * ratio);
    int realHeight = (int) (mImageHeight * ratio);

    int imageLeft = (contentWidth - realWidth) / 2;
    int imageTop = (contentHeight - realHeight) / 2;
    int imageRight = imageLeft + realWidth;
    int imageBottom = imageTop + realHeight;
    mImageRect.set(imageLeft, imageTop, imageRight, imageBottom);
}

private int dp2px(int dip) {
    Context context = this.getContext();
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int px = Math
            .round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    dip, resources.getDisplayMetrics()));
    return px;
}
```

}
and here:

```
     inPath = absPath;
    String fileName = file.getName();
    String parent = file.getParent();
    int index = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    String stem = fileName.substring(0, index);
    String newStem = stem + "_mosaic";
    fileName = fileName.replace(stem, newStem);
    outPath = parent + "/" + fileName;
```

here is related to what you find.

Comment: yes i check it and it is ok

Comment: no Now I understand what you said. my image don't save at all no gallery no sdcard

Comment: I also add permission but It still no result

Comment: You are not saving to gallery as that is impossible to begin wirh. You are saving to a file in outPath. Please tell what the value of outPath is. Of course you will not see that file directly in the Gallery app.

Comment: it is my path where to save it:
  fileName = fileName.replace(stem, newStem);
  outPath = parent + "/" + fileName;

Comment: how to save directly to save in my gallery ?

Comment: You did not tell the value of outPath. Please tell.

Comment: it is string and it is the addres of my filename

Comment: Yes i know. But i asked what the value is. That what you call address. What is exactly that path? For instance `String outPath="theonenextdoor";`. The value i asked for is `theonenextdoor` in this case.

Comment: i edit my code, would you please check it

Comment: Why should I? I asked for a value. Please first tell that value. After that we can see further.

Comment: sorry, look now I put Log just before that line to save.and I put outpath to show . it show the value of out path: /storage/emulated/0/PhotoCollage_app/image1467190047806_mosaic.png

Comment: and I dont have sdcard

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with micro-SD yes or no I think. Now tell us how you check that the file /storage/emulated/0/PhotoCollage_app/image1467190047806_mosaic.png is not created. How do you check it's existence? As said before: The Gallery app will of course not show it. Which app do you use to check?

Comment: My image save successfully but I dont have such address in my device.

Comment: ??????????????????????????? Of course that path exists.

Comment: and i just have gallery to show the pictures.

Comment: You need a file explorer app like ES File Explorer to check if that image is there in that path. The Gallery app is of no use.

Comment: Can I check it with file brower? or file manager?

Comment: Finally I found it. Thank you